# pandas replace NaT with strings in columns when trying to get timedelta object days

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have the following `df`,

```
A         B
3 days    NaT
NaT       1 days
4 days    3 days
NaT       NaT
```

the `dtype` of `A` and `B` is `timedelta64[ns]`, I am tring to get `days` from each `timedelta` of the two columns, so first I tried to remove all the rows with `A` and `B` happened to be all `NaT`,

```
daydelta = df.dropna(subset=['A', 'B'], how='all')
```

and then get `days` on each column value,

```
daydelta[['A', 'B']] = daydelta[['A', 'B']].applymap(lambda x: int(Timedelta(x).days))
```

but it failed since there is no `days` attribute in `NaT`. I am wondering how to get `days` from `timedelta` value, while replacing `NaT` with a string `timedelta value does not exist`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`dt.days`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.days.html) which working with `NaT` too:

```
print (df['A'].dt.days)
0    3.0
1    NaN
2    4.0
3    NaN
Name: A, dtype: float64

df[['A', 'B']] = df[['A', 'B']].apply(lambda x: x.dt.days)
print (df)
     A    B
0  3.0  NaN
1  NaN  1.0
2  4.0  3.0
3  NaN  NaN
```

Comment: got an error `'Timedelta' object has no attribute 'dt'`, no idea why

Comment: What is `print (df.dtypes)` ?

Comment: it is `timedelta64[ns]`

Comment: For all columns?

Comment: yes, so i figured it out, if i use `apply`, there is no issue, but if i use `applymap`, above error occured. dont know why `applymap` does not work here

Comment: Because `applymap` working with each cell separately, working elementwise. and `dt.days` working only with columns, for scalar is not implemented.